# 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, gmail, nodemailer, smtp-auth

I am using node mailer with smtp-pool to sending Mail When I run the app I get this error.
my user and pass and host every thing is right but i face this error.

email.js

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpPool = require('nodemailer-smtp-pool');


const sendEnquiryEmail = function (enquiryData) {
 let FromUserName = 'Chat2cars';
 nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
     var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpPool({

         host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
         port: 587,
          auth: {
             user: 'user@gmail.com',
             pass: 'mypass'
         },
         maxConnections: 5,
         maxMessages: 10
 }));

module.exports = {
sendEnquiryEmail: sendEnquiryEmail
}
```

And i face this Error

````
Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (D:\CHAT_CAR\Node\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:528:15)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (D:\CHAT_CAR\Node\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:1231:30)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (D:\CHAT_CAR\Node\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:319:22)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (D:\CHAT_CAR\Node\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:669:16)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (D:\CHAT_CAR\Node\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:493:10)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 Authentication Credentials Invalid',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions in order of likelihood to help.

1. Double check you have the correct password
2. Check if the user has 2fa enabled if so you will need an [apps password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)
3. Check your [Captcha loc](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
4. Look into [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)